# Where is the Road Graph panel?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to use the Road Graph plugin within QGIS 1.8 (running under Windows 7 64-bit). When I click Vector -> Road Graph -> Settings I get the settings-panel:
[image]

But, I don't know how to enable the "working-panel", which should appear on the left side of the main window, according to the [producers of the plugin](http://gis-lab.info/qa/road-graph-eng.html) (screenshot of pic #2 is taken from their site):

[image]

Any hints? What am I doing wrong / what's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to "View" menu - "Panels" and check "Shortest path" there.